# How to print text value of the div element in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, console.log

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRgez.png)

Hey guys,
I am new to Cypress and have a hard time finding solution for this problem. The #label element which is a div has a text value and I dont know how to print it to a web console. Appreciate all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .find('selector')
  .find('selector')
  .find('selector')
  .eq(0)
  .find('selector')
  .eq(1)
  .find('#label')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    cy.log(text) //logs the text
  })
```